# How do I change tenses when describing my thoughts about the past within a past tense narrative?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, verbs, past-tense

I am probably missing something very simple, but when you have a present + past simple sentence like the following:

*I think that he looked uncomfortable when he was reading my essay.*

How do you put it into a past tense narrative? Do you backshift like you would do with reported speech?

For example, I am more inclined to say:
*I thought that he'd looked uncomfortable, when he'd been reading my essay.*

But it seems like a heavy sentence, no? It does not seem fluent? However, if I try to use simple past it carries a different meaning to me. For example,

*I thought that he looked uncomfortable when he was reading my essay.*

This option makes me feel that all the actions occurred more or less at the same time (as if I thought about him being uncomfortable while looking at him reading my essay), even though in the initial sentence they did not. How do you handle cases like that?

Comment: Are you asking about how to backshift your first sentence in reported speech? If so, you'd have to have some reporting verb, like "She said that...", but I don't see one.

Comment: Do *not* be "more inclined" to use more complicated verb forms unless you have some specific *reason*. Your first and simplest version is probably best. Most likely even if you *did* think that at the time, you still think it *now*. But in that case you'd normally only explicitly call attention to having thought it *earlier* if you specifically wanted to imply something like *I **thought** he looked uncomfortable right back then, but I said nothing. Perhaps if I'd called the doctor he wouldn't have died of a heart attack*.

Comment: *he'd looked uncomfortable, when he'd been reading my essay* is ridiculous overuse of totally unnecessary Perfect forms (it's a "syntactically valid, but irritating" writing style).

Comment: It's not exactly like reported speech. Imagine I am thinking right now about him reading my essay two hours ago (original sentence), then two more hours in the future, I write it down describing how two hours ago I thought about something that happened four hours ago. I really think the past perfect version is an overkill. So I should avoid that? Then is past simple okay or is there a better way to say something like this? Should I stick to the original sentence even when telling a story set in the past?

Comment: Were you watching him read the essay and looking uncomfortable, or are you guessing that he probably looked uncomfortable at the time?

Comment: Could be a total guess (where I never saw him read it) or a situation where I watched him read it but realized how he felt only later. Basically, I had no idea that he looked uncomfortable before having that thought.

Comment: Or, for example, a more detailed scenario: I re-read my essay after receiving a grade and found out that I had accidentally put in an awkward detail or something like that. Now I think that probably it wasn't very comfortable for him to read it. If, now, I wanted to put that thinking into a past narrative, how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

What about: "I thought that he had looked uncomfortable when reading my essay"?